# How to extra text between a html tag in Selenium?

Tags: javascript, selenium

This is my 2nd day into learning Selenium. I would like to extract text between these html tags called .

HTML Code Sample:

```html
<div id="media-buttons" class="hide-if-no-js"/>

<textarea id="DescpRaw" class="ckeditor" name="DescpRaw" rows="13" cols="100" style="visibility: hidden; display: none;">

Cactus spines are produced from specialized structures 
called areoles, a kind of highly reduced branch. Areoles 
are an identifying feature of cacti. 

</textarea>
</div>
```

Required results:

```
Cactus spines are produced from specialized structures 
called areoles, a kind of highly reduced branch. Areoles 
are an identifying feature of cacti.
```

I have tried with Selenium driver below, but it comes out empty.

```js
String bodyhtml = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//textarea[@name='DescpRaw']")).getText();
```

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried getting the `innerHTML` attribute? I think that's what you are wanting. Hint: If you open a browser's debug window, you can usually find the attribute you're looking for. On Chrome or FF, press the <F12> key.

Answer (score 1):

```
String bodyhtml = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//textarea[@name='DescpRaw']")).getAttribute("innerHTML");
```

also I recommend using ID since it is available and it is faster.

```
String bodyhtml = driver.findElement(By.id("DescpRaw")).getAttribute("innerHTML");
```

Comment: Thank you. getAttribute("innerHTML") works perfectly!

Comment: Yeah no problem. If you could mark this as the answer it would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

A couple things...

1. If an element has an ID, you should always prefer to use the ID. By HTML standards, it should be unique on the page so it is the ideal identifier for any element.
2. The problem you are running into is that the `TEXTAREA` is hidden. You can tell this given `style="visibility: hidden; display: none;"` on the element. Selenium is designed to interact with the webpage as a user would. Any element that isn't visible, Selenium won't interact with. The ideal situation would be to figure out how to expose or make visible the textarea field... click some button/link/whatever and *then* get the text from it. With a `TEXTAREA` field you will likely need to `.getAttribute("value")` on the element.

   A couple alternatives to making the element visible are to use Javascript to grab the element text or to use `.getAttribute("innerHTML")` as others have suggested.